# Lifespan of Rachael and other Replicants?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner, blade-runner-2049

Sort of an obvious question: How can the Replicant leader have lived from the birth of the baby until now? Did Wallace start making a new variety of Replicants while Rachael was still alive? I guess Wallace bought out Tyrell soon after he was murdered.

I am pretty sure that Rachael had the same limited lifespan that Batty and the others did.

Comment: The Tyrell Corporation continued making replicants as later as 2022, several years after Tyrell's murder, and knock-off Nexus-8 models were being made up to 2027, according to the tie-in comics. That's where Sapper Morton and Freysa Sadeghpour (the leader of the Replicant rebellion) came from.

Answer (score 5):

Rachael was a [Nexus-*7*](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Nexus-7) android. Evidently they had an elongated lifespan as well as the capacity to bear live young. Note that Wallace is very keen to learn how the latter task was accomplished (to the point of committing multiple crimes including kidnapping and torture) but natural lifespans were incorporated into Tyrell's [Nexus-8](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Nexus-8) and Wallace's [Nexus-9](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Nexus-9) models.

> **NIANDER WALLACE:** **I cannot breed them. I have tried, so help
> me. Tyrell’s final puzzle in adamantine chains and penal Fire.**
>
> We need more Replicants than can ever be assembled. Millions so we can
> be trillions. More. Worlds beyond worlds, diamond shores. We could
> storm Eden and retake her...
>
> **His last trick. Procreation. Perfected... then lost. There is a child.
> Finally unearthed.** Bring it to me. Bring it to me. Bring it to me.
>
> <sub><sup>[Blade Runner 2049 - Final Shooting Script](https://thescriptsavant.com/pdf/blade_runner%20(2049).pdf)</sup></sub>

And from the [Theatrical version voiceover](https://www.trussel.com/bladerun.htm) of *Blade Runner*:

> **Deckard:** *Gaff had been there, and let her live. Four years, he figured. He was wrong. **Tyrell had told me Rachael was special: no termination date.** I didn't know how long we had together. Who does?*